# How to organize all the different parameters in a separated file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, parameters, constants

I am writing a long code that uses many constants, file names, flags, etc. I want to organize all of them neatly in a separate text file named `parameters.py` and hopefully call them as

```
import parameters as p

print(p.Constants.speed_of_light)
print(p.Constants.mass_of_sun)
print(p.Constants.hour2seconds)

print(p.Flags.make_plot)
print(p.Flags.save_results)
print(p.Flags.print_results)

print(p.File_names.results)
print(p.File_names.backup)
print(p.File_names.diagnostic)
```

I expect the output of above to be something like:

```
3e8
2e30
3600

True
False
True

'file1.txt'
'file2.txt'
'file3.txt'
```

I am still a beginner at Python so I am not sure how to achieve it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, parameters.py should look like

```
class Constants:
    speed_of_light = 3e8

class Flags:
   make_plot = True

class File_names:
    results = 'file1.txt'
```

Comment: I guess that the term to refer to `Constants`, `Flags` and `File_names` is "classes". Could you please tell me the term to refer to `speed_of_light`, `make_plot` and `results`. As I said before, I am still new at Python hence I lack a lot of that useful language.

Comment: Those are variables.

Comment: [Quoted from the original documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html): "By the way, I use the word attribute for any name following a dot — for example, in the expression `z.real`, `real` is an attribute of the object `z`. Strictly speaking, references to names in modules are attribute references: in the expression `modname.funcname`, `modname` is a module object and funcname is an attribute of it."

Answer (score 0):

You can do that just as you said. Create parameters.py in the same directory and declare classes(constants, flags etc) with variables in it. Then you can use them with the code you wrote here.